# Clicking on a div inside a table header is clicking the parent header instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using a jquery table plugin that sorts the rows when you click on a column header. I am trying to implement a feature where you can remove a column by clicking an 'X' inside the header. My headers look like `<th><div class="remove-column">X</div>Total Cases</th>`
and I have a click event listener on the remove-column class. When I click the X, instead of hiding the column like I would like, the rows sort.

My function for hiding the table is not even being called. Is this possibly a styling issue, or something else entirely?

More code for some clarity. I am using Backbone as well:

event listener

```
   events: {
      'click .remove-column': 'removeColumn'
    }
```

and the function to be called:

```
removeColumn: function(e){
    debugger
    var columnIndex = $(e.currentTarget).parent().index();
    $('table tr td:nth-child('+columnIndex+')')
  }
```

and the CSS(less) looks like this:

```
   thead {
          tr {
            td, th {
              position: relative;
              .remove-column {
                position: absolute;
                right: 3px;
                opacity: 0.0;
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: It would be really nice to have a http://jsfiddle.net/ that reproduces the issue

Comment: @mcabral http://jsfiddle.net/q2guD/

Unfortunately, this doesn't reproduce the issue, which leads me to believe its a problem with the plugin interfering

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop event from bubbling. Use `e.stopPropagation()` to stop the event from bubbling up.

```
$('.remove-column').on('click', function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   //Your code
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the function is never even called, so I can't even get this far.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `preventDefault` on the sort method's click event and then remove. Something like the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.remove-column').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();   //Stop the default action
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

Alternatively you can also look into `event.stopPropagation` method or use `return false;` to stop the default behaviour.